# How do I hide the navigation and status bar in an android app using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fullscreen

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar and status bar in an app but just pasting in `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` and `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);` into the main() method did not work. Here's the code of the main() method-

```
Future<void> main(List<String> args) async {
  final container = await preInit(args);

  runApp(RefenaScope.withContainer(
    container: container,
    child: TranslationProvider(
      child: const LocalSendApp(),
    ),
  ));
}
```

The App runs like normal, only the IDE is warning me with "missing an 'await' for the 'Future' computed by this expression". I didn't see any errors in the terminal.

Comment: Provide why they didn't work? any errors

Comment: It says "missing an 'await'  for the 'Future' computed by this expression" .

Comment: you should provide any error is the question as well